# Number of arrangements of letters with repetition permitted under stated constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I have a lot of difficulty with probability so I'd like to know if I am thinking correctly:

Considering an alphabet with $21$ consonants and $5$ vowels, how many words with $4$ letters exist:

(i) Exactly $1$ vowel and allowing repetitions

I did $5 \cdot 21 \cdot 21 \cdot 21 \cdot 4$ (the $4$ is to vary the position of the vowel)

(ii) Starting and ending with x, having at least one vowel and allowing repetitions

I did $1 \cdot 5 \cdot 26 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 - 5$ (the $2$, to vary the positions of the vowel and the other letter and the $-5$ to exclude cases where the vowel is repeated so the order doesn't matter)

(iii) Having exactly one x letter and not allowing repetitions

$1 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 4$ (the $4$, to vary the position of the x)

Is my logic right?

Comment: A strategy, not an answer. When you think you have a method for problems like this, test your answer for small instances where you can write everything down. Here, perhaps   $3$ letter words on a $3$ letter alphabet with $1$ or $2$ vowels.

Comment: (ii) Starting and **ending** with 'x' ...

is that what you mean?

Comment: Where does probability come into it other than your answers are probably correct?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Your answer is correct.

(ii) I assume you mean the words starting and ending with 'x'. Consider this array: x _ _ x . We can fill in the blanks with any letter from the alphabet, as long as the word has at least 1 vowel. We count the number of ways to do this by first counting all permutations of 2 letters with repetitions, then subtracting the permutations that include no vowels (hence, made entirely of consonants). The correct answer is:
$$26 \times 26 - 21 \times 21 $$
(iii) Your answer is correct.